# CSS - Text aligning on top regardless of flexbox properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

i'd like to know why is the text "Check out my work" aligned on top of the flexbox instead of the center, regardless of the flexbox values.
Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/don0ts/pen/JByjqO

The code:
 flexbox container:

```
#work {
 color:white;
 width:100%;
 height:800px;
 background-color:rgb(235, 73, 67);
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 justify-content:center;
 align-content:center;
 border-bottom:3px solid rgba(48,48,57,0.1);
}
```

grid container inside the flexbox container:

```
.grid-container{
 margin:auto;
 display:grid;
 grid-template- columns:repeat(5,1fr);
 grid-gap:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<section id="work">
 <header><h1>Check out my work</h1></header>
 <div class="grid-container">
 </div>    
</section>
```

More details in the codepen link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `margin: auto;` for the `.grid-container`.
Please update it with:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Or any other value than 0

If you'll use `margin: auto;` that means you'll have all margins set to `auto`

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

Which means it will take whole available space in your case.

Comment: @TemaniAfif That will solve the problem, margin: 0 auto basically means your top and bottom margins will be 0px, whilst your left and right will be automatic. At the moment your setting everything to be auto

Comment: Am not discussing the solution but the wording ;) ... why saying *please*?